# Android: Audio streaming from firebase storage using up too much data

Tags: android, firebase, audio, firebase-storage, audio-streaming

I am creating a music streaming application in which audio files are stored on firebase storage. I used the Mediaplayer class to stream the audio from the storage using the audio file's download url like this...

```
 try {
            mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("Download URL"); 
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The audio stream gets played fine but uses up too much data...i streamed a song for around 40 to 50 mins and exceeded my daily 1 gb data download limit ([Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing))...
Am i streaming the data the right way? or is that the amount of data a normal audio stream consumes?

i read somewhere that [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) is better than androids Mediaplayer class for audio streaming should i use that instead?

Comment: 1gb in 50 minutes is about 320kbps. That is a pretty high bitrate, but not totally uncommon. What bitrate are the files encoded at?

Comment: Files are encoded at 320kbps but according to this [article] (https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidcentral.com/how-much-data-does-streaming-media-use%3famp) 320kbps stream uses around 115 mbs per hour.That should be enough for 9 hours of music streaming for a gb

Comment: I think you forgot a zero 320,000 x 60 x 60 = 1.15gbh

Comment: Hey guys I wanted to know if how the playerview can be hidden when streaming audio with no artwork...I want to hide the black screen or have it wrap around the controls